# How to get deployed contract address using Truffle 3.x console?

Tags: truffle

I opened truffle console and when I type my contract's name, I see a very long message on the console but not sure How do I deploy the contract and find the deployed contract address. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$truffle console
truffle(development)>compile
truffle(development)>migrate
truffle(development)>contract_name.new().then(function(res) { sc = contract_name.at(res.address) })
truffle(development)>sc.address
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here and using Truffle v5+, use `.address` after a call to `await ContractName.new()`. For example:

```
some_erc20_contract_instance = await ERC20.new()
console.log(`address: ${some_erc20_contract_instance.address}`)
```