# Calling Solidity functions from Truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle

This might be a double, but I have seen different answers so far, and it's very confusing. I have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Sum {
   event Summed(uint256 num1, uint256 num2, uint256 result);

   function getSum(uint256 num1, uint256 num2) public returns (uint256 result) {
       uint256 result;
       result = num1 + num2;
       return result;

       Summed(num1, num2, result);
   }
}
```

How to call the `getSum()` from the Truffle Console starting from initiating the contract (I'm using Ganache), and what is the difference (in terms of syntax) in calling the `getSum()` from the Console and by using the Web3js?

I'm using the latest versions of Truffle and Ganache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the `pure` modifier to your `getSum()` function so it does what you want it to do. Then deploy it with `$ truffle migrate`.

Then `$ truffle console`

```
> var sum;
undefined

> Sum.deployed().then(function(instance) { sum = instance; });

> sum
A lot of truffle contract stuff ... 

> var a = 1;
> var b = 2;
> var response;
> sum.getSum(a,b).then(function(r) { response = r.toString(10); }); // because r is a bigNumber

> response
3
>
```

I'm just sort of winging it, so I hope I didn't flub the syntax.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is retrieving the `return result;` The event emitter would never fire because it comes after the `return`. Listening to events on the client side is a different technique.

Comment: Any source to read about event listening?

Comment: Have look over here. The essence of it is you would do something like `sum.Summed.watch(function(error,result) { // what to do when event discovered });` https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/truffle-web3-event-listeners-returns-nothing

Answer (score 1):

If the contract has been deployed:

```
  Sum.at(-address-).getSum(param1, param2)
```

If it has not been deployed follow the steps in this answer to deploy it and get the address:

[How to get deployed contract address using Truffle 3.x console?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18574/how-to-get-deployed-contract-address-using-truffle-3-x-console)

Comment: Thanks. That's really weird, as this works for some functions, but for others it doesn't (invalid JSON rpc error).

Comment: This was the only helpful answer as this references the deployed contract using its address. The other answers rely on creating a local instance which is nice for pre-testing but not for talking to a contract which is already deployed to the ledger.